# UITableView issue on setScrollIndicatorInsets and setContentInset

Tags: uitableview, uikeyboard

I have custom tableview with 4 sections.

1st section consists of "TextField".

2nd and 3rd Consists of Label.

4th section consists of "TextArea".

I have registered for "UIKeyboardWillShowNotification". I am calling "keyboardWillShow" function as shown below.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    NSValue *keyboardBoundsValue = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [keyboardBoundsValue getValue:&keyboardBounds];
    UIEdgeInsets e = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardBounds.size.height + 80, 0);
    [eventTableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:e];
    [eventTableView setContentInset:e];
}
```

Adding custom cells to tableview as shown below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if([indexPath section] == 0 || [indexPath section] == 4)
    {
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if([indexPath section] == 0)
            {
                UITextField* titleTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 280, cell.bounds.size.height)];
                [titleTextField setTag:201];
                [titleTextField setPlaceholder:@"Title"];
                [titleTextField setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:YES];
                [titleTextField setDelegate:self];
                [titleTextField setClipsToBounds:YES];
                [[cell contentView]addSubview:titleTextField];

                [titleTextField release];
            }
            else if([indexPath section] == 4)
            {
                UITextView* messageTextView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 280, 2 * cell.bounds.size.height)];
                [messageTextView setTag:206];
                [messageTextView setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:YES];
                [messageTextView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                [messageTextView setDelegate:self];
                [messageTextView setClipsToBounds:YES];
                [[cell contentView]addSubview:messageTextView];

                [messageTextView release];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

            if([indexPath section] == 1)
            {
                if([indexPath row] == 0)
                {
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Start";
                    [cell setTag:202];
                }
                else if([indexPath row] == 1)
                {
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"End";
                    [cell setTag:203];
                }
            }

            else if([indexPath section] == 2)
            {       
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Reminder";
                [cell setTag:204];
            }
            else if([indexPath section] == 3)
            {        
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Add Photo";
                [cell setTag:205];
            }
        }
    }

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    return cell;
}
```

When I click on textView, keyboard notification is received and thus tableview scrolls-up to accommodate keyboard. But when I resign the keyboard on "textviewDidEndEditing", the cells of tableview exchanges.

This is the code of textviewDidEndEditing.

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    UIEdgeInsets e = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    [eventTableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:e];
    [eventTableView setContentInset:e];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Please help me out with this. I don't know why the cells are being exchanged when keyboard appears and when I resignFirstResponder of textfield and textView. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[textField superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found answer on my own. As I am allocating TextField and TextArea by using the same "CellIdentifier", its creating problem.

So, I created 2 Custom UITableViewCell in xib. One for Custom TextField cell and one for Custom TextView cell and gave Cell identifiers namely "TitleCell" and "MessageCell" respectively. Now I went to cellForRowAtIndexPath function and gave "TitleCell" as identifier for [indexPath section] == 0 and "MessageCell" as identifier for [indexPath section] == 4.

That's it. My problem was solved. Thank you :)